# converting Java code to Android

Tags: java, android, methods

I Have a Java application and I need to convert it to an Android application
is there any resources to show how ? in Android developer site I didnt found anything like that!

I need to use the Java methods and classes in android ,How it can be done?

Comment: You may want to clarify the question. Are you looking for a guide to common problems when trying to do  this? You almost certainly won't be able to do a straight conversion as you won't have access to all the core java libraries.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the standard android SDK (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) all code is already done in JAVA and should already work in android. Just follow the instructions to set up eclipse and android sdk tools and then import your code to an android project.

The only thing that must be changed is the GUI (graphical user interface) since it's different in android. Do the "hello world" tutorial and "Hello, Views" tutorial in the android sdk page that should put you in the right track of how you should do GUI's in android ;)

Comment: I've created a new project and copied all the files again and it works!!